# How to find minimum distance between a point and the boundary of a circular sector

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How can I find the minimum distance between a given point $P$ and the boundary of a circular sector in the trigonometric circle (represented in green)?

The angle $\theta$ is given and is limited to $180^\circ$ (which would occupy the upper half of the circle).

[image]

I'm interested in any trick or elegant way of solving this, if there is any. I'm using this in a programming language so I'd like to reduce the number of operations.

I already solved this in the straight-forward method:

- taking distances $d_1$ and $d_2$ from $P$ to each of the mirrored lines;
- taking distance $d_3 = 1 - \|P\|$ from $P$ to the surface.
- and the answer would be $d = min(d_1, d_2, d_3)$.

Comment: The word *surface* in your title is very confusing.

Comment: "slice of a circle" $\to$ "circular sector".

Comment: This is not Linear Algebra. Please, choose the appropriate tags for your questions.

Comment: There is no other method other than your method.  You've already solved your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to reduce the number of operations

I believe there is no elegant solution but since you using a programming language you can reduce operation by avoiding calculation of the one of the distances $d_1$ or $d_2$, and instead use geometric logic to judge if $d_1 \le d_2$ or vice-versa.

If we redefine the picture as such

[image: Bisect]

We bisect $\angle\theta$ into two sectors of equal angle $1$ and $2$ respectively. Now, if $P$ is in sector $2$, then $d_2 \le d_1$ and vice versa. We do not need to calculate $d_1$ or $d_2$. All you need is the $P_x$ and the x-coordinate of where bisector meet the arc ($B_x$). Then a few boolean statements comparing the coordinates (`if... else`) should do. It would be something like this:

```
boolean dis1, dis2 = false;
private boolean smallestDis(Bx, Px){

if(Bx != Px){

   if(Bx < Px) {
      return dis2 = true;
   } else{
      return dis1 = true;
   }
}

return false; 

}
```

Assume $P$ is indeed in sector $2$. Now, continue calculating $d_2$ and $d_3$, and compare them.

```
...
if(!smallestDis(0.0, Px)) //d1 = d2 (Do something about it?);

double sDistance = 0.0;

if(dis1) {
  sDistance = min(calculateD1(), calculateD3());
} else {
  sDistance = min(calculateD2(), calculateD3());
}
```